# Using .hgignore Android Studio

Tags: android, mercurial, atlassian-sourcetree

I want to use Mercurial Version Control with my project. I am doing the same using Source Tree. Here while doing I am getting one problem, that whenever I run the project, all the build files also shows a change and needs to commited everytime I run the code. For solution I used .hgignore file, placed in my root directory

Here are the contents of my .hgignore file

```
syntax: glob
*.iml
*.idea
*.orig
bin/**
.gradle/**
.idea/**
build/**
gen/**
*~
/\#*
.*.swp
.DS-Store
local.properties
```

I think there might be something wrong, because of which that build files are not ignoring at all, please help

Comment: try to remove and re-add files from version control tracking

Comment: You mean I should re-import the project ? or reset the complete repository ?

Comment: try "hg forget" command for files, that you want remove from tracking. for example "hg forget *.iml" and so on